# how to parse iframe in lxml in python?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, lxml, lxml.html

I found that lxml can't parse heml element of iframe .

```
import lxml.html
from urllib.request import urlopen
import os
url="http://news.163.com/special/mhmingdan/?bdsj"
file=urlopen(url).read()
root=lxml.html.document_fromstring(file)
tab=root.xpath('//iframe')
```

How can make lxml get the html element of iframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use forward slashes `//` instead of backslashes `\\`:

```
tab = root.xpath('//iframe')
```

Also, you can simplify getting the page and parsing by passing `urlopen` results directly to the `parse()`:

```
root = lxml.html.parse(urlopen(url))
```

Comment: i have corrected it ,but why i can not get the iframe?

Comment: @it_is_a_literature first of all, you should not have edited the question. Also, if you print out `tab` you'll see that the `iframe` element is found.

Comment: there is a table node under the iframe ,why i can't get it?

Answer (score -2):

```
page = requests.get(url)  
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
src_url = tree.cssselect("iframe") 
print src_url[0].attrib
```